# How to save syncfusion pivot view tool bar options as well with table meta data

Tags: angular, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I am using Syncfusion pivot View, Here I have a requirement of saving Multiple charts on button click and loading charts on button click.
I am able to save and load data using getPersistData() and loadPersistData().
But I want to save toolbar selections as well like if the user has selected Bar for Chart 1 and Line for Chart 2 then on loading these charts again on button click Chart 1 should load as Bar chart and Chart 2 will load as Line chart.
any configuration which user has done using toolbar like if the user has selected grid or 1 pivot view and charts for 2nd pivot view on loading them again I want to load as per their previous selections.

Answer (score 1):

We have analyzed your requirement and prepared a pivot sample using toolbar feature to save and load pivot report with the current view (table or chart) and chart type. Kindly refer to the following sample and code example.

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsd4c1?file=app.component.ts

**Code Example:**

```
loadReport(args: any) {
    let reportCollection: string[] = [];
    if (localStorage.pivotviewReports && localStorage.pivotviewReports !== "") {
        reportCollection = JSON.parse(localStorage.pivotviewReports);
    }
    reportCollection.map(function (item: any): void {
        if (args.reportName === item.reportName) {
            args.report = item.report;
        }
    });
    if (args.report) {
        var report = JSON.parse(args.report);
        this.pivotObj.chartSettings.chartSeries.type = report.chartSettings.chartSeries.type;
        this.pivotObj.displayOption = report.displayOption;
        this.pivotObj.currentView = report.displayOption.primary === 'Chart' ? 'Chart' : 'Table';
        this.pivotObj.dataSourceSettings = report.dataSourceSettings;
    }
}
```